# HPLIP missing packages

Tags: hp

Ubuntu 18.04.1, HPLIP 3.17.10.

I am trying to install HPLIP using Synaptic. The installation reports no errors.  But, when I start the HP system tray, I get this error message:

```
File "/usr/bin/hp-toolbox", line 269, in <module>
     QApplication, ui_package = utils.import_dialog(ui_toolkit)
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Also, the HP icon in the tray area does nothing if I click on it - although I am able to start the HPLIP Toolbox, and that seems to work.

When I run `hp-check`, it tells me that the following packages are missing/incompatible, and that I need to install them manually:

```
libnetsnmp-devel
snmp-mibs-downloader
libsnmp-dev
```

I do not know where to find the first two, nor how to install them manually.

Regarding `libsnmp-dev`:  It is not installed, but via Synaptic versions *5.7.3+dfsg-1.8ubuntu3* and *5.7.3+dfsg-1.8ubuntu3.1* are available to install.  However, when I try to install `libsnmp-dev` via Synaptic, it tells me that the following packages will be removed - but I don't want them to be removed (especially `npm`):

```
libssl1.0-dev
node-gyp
nodejs-dev
npm
```

How do I get the missing packages installed, get HPLIP working, get rid of the error message (above), and make the HP system tray to work, without uninstalling `npm` and those other packages?

Output of the `apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev node-gyp nodejs-dev npm`:

```
libssl1.0-dev:
  Installed: 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.2
  Candidate: 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.2
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.2n-1ubuntu5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

node-gyp:
  Installed: 3.6.2-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.6.2-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 3.6.2-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

nodejs-dev:
  Installed: 8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4
  Candidate: 8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4
  Version table:
 *** 8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages
     8.10.0~dfsg-2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages

npm:
  Installed: 3.5.2-0ubuntu4
  Candidate: 3.5.2-0ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 3.5.2-0ubuntu4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Output of `sudo apt install libsnmp-dev`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp libjs-async libjs-inherits libjs-node-uuid libuv1-dev node-abbrev
  node-ansi node-ansi-color-table node-archy node-async node-balanced-match
  node-block-stream node-brace-expansion node-builtin-modules
  node-combined-stream node-concat-map node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream
  node-forever-agent node-form-data node-fs.realpath node-fstream
  node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git node-glob node-graceful-fs
  node-hosted-git-info node-inflight node-inherits node-ini
  node-is-builtin-module node-isexe node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile
  node-lru-cache node-mime node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream
  node-node-uuid node-nopt node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once
  node-osenv node-path-is-absolute node-pseudomap node-qs node-read
  node-read-package-json node-request node-retry node-rimraf node-semver
  node-sha node-slide node-spdx-correct node-spdx-expression-parse
  node-spdx-license-ids node-tar node-tunnel-agent node-underscore
  node-validate-npm-package-license node-which node-yallist    
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.    
The following additional packages will be installed:    
  libpci-dev libsensors4-dev libssl-dev libssl-doc libudev-dev libwrap0-dev    
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libssl1.0-dev node-gyp nodejs-dev npm
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpci-dev libsensors4-dev libsnmp-dev libssl-dev libssl-doc libudev-dev
  libwrap0-dev
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 4 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,843 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,932 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev node-gyp nodejs-dev npm`. If you installed those packages from unofficial sources, you may have no other choice but to uninstall them or revert to the official versions.

Comment: fkraiem, I have edited my original question to show the output you asked for at the end of the question.  Also, as I recall, I installed these from "standard" Ubuntu repositories using Synaptic.

Comment: Yes, everything seems good so far. Please add the output of `sudo apt install libsnmp-dev` so we can see what exactly is bothering Apt.

Comment: For me it seems that `libsnmp-dev` is not a real problem. To clarify please retry full HPLIP installation with `sudo apt install hplip-gui --reinstall` and add output of `apt-cache policy hplip-data hplip hplip-gui` and `hp-systray -x -g` to the question. Do you have custom Python3 and/or local python modules from `pip3`?

Comment: fkraiem:  I added the output of sudo apt install libsnmp-dev to my original question.

Comment: N0rbert:  I do not understand your Python3 question.  How would I know if I have a "custom" version?  

Also - Here is the output of the apt-cache policy command  you asked for.  It would not work the way you asked me to input it:  

main1@system1:~$ sudo apt-cache policy hplip-data hplip hplip-gui hp-systray -x -g

[sudo] password for main1: 

E: Command line option 'x' [from -x] is not understood in combination with the other options.

main1@system1:~$

Comment: Are you still facing the issue or is it solved? Please ping me using `@Kulfy` otherwise I might miss the reply.

Comment: @Kulfy , I am no longer facing this issue.  I don't recall for sure what I did - I think I just gave up, followed HP's instructions to totally uninstall, and then reinstall all over again.  I can't say that I solved it.

Comment: This solved the issue for the: https://askubuntu.com/a/1393162/389062