# Ubuntu 20.04 - Simplescan just scan page on flatbed and ignores feeder of my HP scanner

Tags: 20.04, hp, scanner

I've recently switched to U20.04 from U16.04.
With U16.04 I was able to use my scanner (HP OfficeJet 3834) and all its capabilities, including scan "All pages from feeder" (`simplescan` option) without installing any additional driver like `hplip`. The scanner is connected via usb. No problem with printing without `hplip`.

The behavior is the following:

1. Open `simplescan`, then press on "All pages from feeder"
2. Pages in the feeder are ignored. Instead, `simplescan` just scans the page on the flatbed. Then, an error is returned (Gtk-like message box which says "Failed to scan" and "Unable to start scan".

It is interesting to notice that if I use the internal webservice (127.0.0.1/60000), I'm able to scan from feeder.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to get the scanner to work on Ubuntu 20.04 and Kubuntu 20.04. I tested it works for **networked** printer "HP Color LaserJet MFP **M277dw**" on **Kubuntu 20.04 LTS**.

- Download the `hplip` installer: **download the `.run` file** [from SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/), nested inside the folder named after the latest version available, which will be referenced to as `VERSION` in the rest of this answer. At the time of writing I found [`hplip-3.20.11.run`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/3.20.11/hplip-3.20.11.run/download) inside the [`3.20.11` folder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/3.20.11/).
- `cd` to the download folder
- Run `chmod +x hplip-VERSION.run`
- **Run `./hplip-VERSION.run`**, initiating `hplip`'s installer
- When asked for the installation mode, **answer `c`**, i.e. custom
- Proceed with the installation using the **default options** (i.e. by pressing `Enter`)
- When you reach the `SELECT HPLIP OPTIONS` section, **answer `n`** to `'Graphical User Interfaces (Qt5)'` **and `y`** to `'Scanning support'`, answer all of the other questions as you wish.
- Proceed the installation with the **default options**
- When asked "Do you want to check for HPLIP updates?" **answer `n`**, since what you have downloaded is already the latest version
- Then the **printer setup** will start. Do as asked until the end and do not worry if `hp-systray` cannot start.

Now `hplip` command line tools should be installed and configured correctly. Try to run `hp-scan` *and* to print something: if everything works as expected, then you are finished, otherwise you may follow the next steps, which involve installing a proprietary `hplip-plugin`, even though your printer may not be marked as requiring a plugin. At this point for me printing worked, but scanning didn't, yielding "Error during device I/O" caused by `XSane`/`hpaio`.

- Run `sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils`
- Run `sudo aa-disable /usr/share/hplip/plugin.py`, it should print "Disabling /usr/share/hplip/plugin.py.". Not doing this step would cause "**Python gobject/dbus may be not installed**" down the line.
- **Run `hp-plugin`** as a normal user, it will open the plugin setup
- **Answer `d`** to the first question, so that an automatic plugin download will start
- If an error such as "Unable to recieve key from keyserver" appears, **answer `y`** to the question "Do you still want to install the plug-in?" to proceed with the installation. This does not seem to have any effect.
- The plugin should start installing automatically. If it does not you can download `hplip-VERSION-plugin.run` from [here](https://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/auxfiles/HP/plugins/) using `wget https://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/auxfiles/HP/plugins/hplip-VERSION-plugin.run` and then running `hp-plugin` again, this time with the `p` option instead of `d`.
- Everything should be working fine now :-D

---

These are, in order, all of the errors I came across:

- missing `pyqt5` package: solved by installing the cli version only, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246680/some-python-packages-could-not-be-installed-during-hplip-3-20-5-installing-on-ub)
- "Error during device I/O" when issuing a scan using the `hpaio` address: solved by installing `hplip-plugin`, see [this bugreport](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1694663)
- "Unable to recieve key from keyserver", ignored
- "Python gobject/dbus may be not installed", solved with `apparmor-utils`, see [this bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1813768)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, this does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem with a new vanilla installation of 20.04.1 with an HP Color Laserjet MFP278-m281 printer.

I found that you need to install the hplip-gui package. I followed these instructions:

In a terminal type `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui`

> To install the plug-in using the GUI you can follow these procedures:
>
> 1. Launch a command-line window and enter:
>
>    ```
>    hp-setup
>    ```
> 2. Select your connection type and click "Next".
> 3. Select your printer from "Selected Devices" list and click "Next".
> 4. Enter your root password when prompted and click "Next".
> 5. Use the recommended installation method and click "Next".
> 6. Check the box to accept with the "Driver Plug-In License Agreement" and click "Next".
> 7. Finish the installation of the printer as normal, however you may be prompted to re-enter your user name and password.
>
> If you run into any additional install problems you can go to our
> [known issues](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/howtos/known) page and check for a solution.
>
> For advanced users who wish to install HPLIP components manually, a
> utility exists (hp-plugin) which will download and install the plugin
> file, but it does not also install a printer queue like hp-setup does.
>
> Do the following:
>
> 1. Launch a command-line window and enter:
>
>    ```
>    hp-plugin
>    ```
> 2. Follow the directions above for navigating the GUI but remember that the printer queue will not be installed through this process.

After that, the scanner worked perfectly well including collecting documents from the document feeder.

[reference](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/binary_plugin.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, I've already followed these steps and I was not able to get the desired result.

Comment: I notived it added another printer... did you try selecting a different one in the list on opening the Document Scanner program rather than just accepting the default selected?

Answer (score 1):

You could modify simple scan .desktop to use a custom script.

Normally located in `/usr/share/applications/simple-scan.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Document Scanner
Comment=Make a digital copy of your photos and documents
Keywords=scan;scanner;flatbed;adf;
Exec=/home/USERNAME/scripts/simpleScan.sh
Icon=org.gnome.SimpleScan
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Graphics;Scanning;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=simple-scan
```

And the script (here in `/home/USERNAME/scripts/simpleScan.sh`), something like:

```
simple-scan $(hp-makeuri 192.168.15.106 | grep ^SANE | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
```