# simple-scan failed to scan, unable to start scan with HP color laser jet pro MFP M477fdw

Tags: 20.04, hp, scanner

I'm trying to get my Ubuntu desktop to scan directly from a HP color laser jet pro MFP M477fdw all-in-one printer/scanner device. The device is on my home network.

simple-scan (the "Document Scanner" app) starts up and detects the scanner, and the "Scan" button is green. When I click the green "Scan" button, the scanner warms up and appears to be working. The scanner touchscreen says "Scanning to Computer". simple-scan then shows a white page but after half a second pops up a dialog that says "Failed to scan ... Unable to start scan" and the only option is to close that dialog.

`scanimage -L` detects the scanner.

```
$ scanimage -L
device `escl:http://10.1.1.80:8080' is a ESCL HP Color LaserJet MFP M477fdw (E0EDEB) flatbed scanner
device `hpaio:/net/hp_color_laserjet_mfp_m477fdw?ip=10.1.1.80&queue=false' is a Hewlett-Packard hp_color_laserjet_mfp_m477fdw all-in-one
```

Workaround: set up a samba share "network folder". The scanner can connect to over the network to save scanned images.

Printing to the device (over my network) works as expected. Ubuntu auto-detects the device as a printer and auto-configures it.

I don't want to [run the hplip GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290731/ubuntu-20-04-simplescan-just-scan-page-on-flatbed-and-ignores-feeder-of-my-hp/1299860) if I don't have to. I just really don't like the blue "HP" icon in my system tray.

Software versions:

- 64-bit Ubuntu GNU/Linux Desktop, 20.04.1 LTS
- simple-scan 3.36.3

Comment: You can suppress the appearance of the "HP" ocon in your system tray - I have. Just right click it and select the appropriate option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working. I ran `sudo apt install hplip-gui` then `hp-setup`. It couldn't discover the scanner so I had to enter its hostname. I chose to *not* add another print queue (it was already there) and *not* add a fax queue.

simple-scan ("Document Scanner") now shows *three* options for scanners. One works. The one that works is named "HP HP_Color_LaserJet_MFP_M477fdw".

I think the important thing hp-setup did was to download a plugin. I had to enter my credentials so it could install the plugin. Then I just skipped printer & fax setup and closed the hp-setup GUI, then ran simple-scan.

I don't see a HP icon in my system tray even after doing this.

Comment: Just want to comment that I had the same problem and followed your solution. And that this did unfortunately not solve the issue for me so there must be more at work than just running hp-setup and getting some unnamed plugin installed. I did finally get things working by simply installing sane-airscan.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but first make sure to run `sudo apt install python3-pyqt5` these commands first.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, and in my case the scan to pc option was disabled in the printer menu. i had to setup an admin password under settings - security in the web interface of the printer and then activate the scan to pc option under settings - security - admin settings in the web interface. after that it was working fine.